# How to convert this equation to telescoping series

Tags: derivatives, summation, binomial-coefficients

If $a_n=(\ln(3))^n(\sum _0 ^n \frac {k^2 (nCk)}{n!})$What is the value of $$a_1+a_2+... a_{\infty}$$.$$\text {Attempt} $$  Now we know $(1+x)^n=\sum _0 ^n  nCk.x^k$ thus differentiating twice wrt x and putting $x=1$ we have $\sum _0 ^n k^2 (nCk)=n (n-1).2^{n-2}+n.2^{n-1} $. That plus  sign seems to block my way. Another idea is that I see n! in denominator that gives me an hint to see if it matches with any of the definitions of $e $. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you put the latex for binomial coefficients I forgot it

Comment: Do you need this to be a telescoping series specifically? Now that you know what $\sum_{0}^{n} k^{2}{{n} \choose {k}}$ is, you can do this directly. The second idea of matching with the definition of $e$ actually works.

Comment: After all, for $n\ge 2$ we have $ \left[ n(n-1)2^{n-2}+n2^{n-1} \right]/n! = 2^{n-2}/(n-2)! + 2^{n-1}/(n-1)! $.

Comment: But how to sum it up upto infinity?

Comment: I got the result. But on paper. Do u want it?

Comment: Shoot, I was already writing the result for some time. I'm sorry if I stole your chance to respond.

Comment: @SpiralRain its all cool in the house.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar [https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsrZZ.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, 
\begin{align*} 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln 3)^{n}}{n!}\left(\sum_{0}^{n} k^{2}{{n}\choose{k}}\right) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln 3)^{n}}{n!}\left[ n(n-1)2^{n-2}+n2^{n-1}\right] \\[1em]
&= \sum_{\color{red}{n=2}}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln 3)^{n}\;2^{n-2}}{(n-2)!} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln 3)^{n}\;2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \\[1em]
&= (\ln 3)^{2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(2\ln 3)^{n-2}}{(n-2)!} + (\ln 3)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2\ln 3)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \\[1em]
&= (\ln 3)^{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2\ln 3)^{n}}{n!} + (\ln 3)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2\ln 3)^{n}}{n!} \\[1em]
&= \left( (\ln 3)^{2} + \ln 3 \right)\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2\ln 3)^{n}}{n!} \right) \\[1em]
&= \left( (\ln 3)^{2} + \ln 3 \right)e^{2\ln 3}.
\end{align*}

If we use the fact that $2\ln 3 = \ln 9$ then our answers simplifies to $9\left( (\ln 3)^{2} + \ln 3 \right)$.